# Testing a ngrx effect that in one case does not dispatch a new action

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx

I have this one effect where some preconditions have to be true so that a specific action gets dispatched:

```
@Effect()
prepareLoadDetails$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(PREPARE_LOAD_DETAILS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store)
    .filter(([actionType, stateStore]) => this.necessarySelectionsMade(stateStore))
    .map(() => {
        return new LoadDetailsAction();
    });
```

Now I'm somehow stuck in unit testing this code. There's no problem getting the LoadDetailsAction dispatched. But how can I test that no action is dispatched in the other cases?

```
describe('prepareLoadDetails$', () => {
    it('should trigger a LoadDetailsAction if all needed selections are made', (done) => {
        // given
        const {runner, effects} = setup({
            // some setup of state here
        });

        // when
        runner.queue(new PrepareLoadDetailsAction());

        // then
        effects.prepareLoadDetails$.subscribe(result => {
            expect(result).toEqual(new LoadDetailsAction());
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should not trigger a LoadDetailsAction if needed selections are not made', (done) => {
        // given
        const {runner, effects} = setup({
            // some other setup of state here
        });

        // when
        runner.queue(new PrepareLoadDetailsAction());

        // then ???
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't have any code nearby. Can you please put debugger into store.dispatch method? I suggest you to check if dispatch of store service is called or not on this code: `.map(() => new LoadDetailsAction())`

Comment: Path to the file: `<projectDir>/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.js`. About 50-60 line.

Comment: I tried. Nope. It won't be called. I wanted to suggest you to spyOn store.dispatch method, but this will not work, sry.

Comment: I'm kinda new to ngrx effects, but maybe these tests from the live example can help you : https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/tree/master/src/app/effects

Comment: Thanks, Alex

`let actionDispatched = false; effects.prepareLoadDetails$.subscribe(() => actionDispatched = true,() => actionDispatched = true,() => actionDispatched = true); expect(actionDispatched).toBeFalsy();`

seems to do the job. Still, I'm not quite sure if this really tests what I want to test :)

Comment: @matt no that does not test what you need. If _any_ of actions will be dispatched your test will show action is dispatched.

Comment: you mean if any other effect 'listens' on type `PREPARE_LOAD_DETAILS`? well, that may be ok, since I explicitly queue that `PrepareLoadDetailsAction` and subscribe on `effects.prepareLoadDetails$`... isn't that enough?

Comment: You need to emit a `new NoopAction()` that does nothing instead of using a filter. You can then test if the action is `NoopAction` or `LoadDetailsAction`. Otherwise, **don't** unit test this edge case. Verify everything else in your app is working as expect. I would assume that testing everything else automatically by definition includes this edge case.